# Creating a webapp to share recorded telephonic interviews, what platform to use?

Tags: github, soundcloud

I have these goals in mind:

1. Upload my recorded telephonic interviews, after removing sensitive/ identifying information.
2. People may contribute to upload their recorded interview as well.
3. Optionally add comments/ answers to the questions.

I whole idea is to help aspiring interviewee to help and prepare with their future interviews.

I am leaning towards **Github**, since there is no storage limit, plus other people may also contribute to it.

Any helpful pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think GitHub can host such a big volume of data (sounds), and uploading would mean cloning (download all existing data) first, I believe, which is almost impossible.

Comment: (A) Are these interviews intended for public consumption, or is this in-house like job interviews? (B) Your Question is vague. How would your needs not be met simply by using a virtual drive space such as Google Drive with folders containing the recording along with a Google Docs file for shared note-writing?

Answer (score 1):

[MediaGoblin](http://mediagoblin.org/) can do that.

While it accepts videos too, I am sure you can configure it to only accept sound files.

It is free and open source (GNU AGPL v3)

Demo server: https://goblinrefuge.com

[image]

Cons:

- As you can tell, the UI is not super trendy.
- No commenting system, it seems.
- Of course you will have to customize it to remove confidential parts of the recordings, or tell users to do it themselves.